# Prevent the Bootstrap accordion collpase on the internal anchor (href) click

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5, accordion

I want to prevent the accordion from collapsing on the new page opening after clicking the anchor element (href). Please find the HTML code below, Can anyone help me with the JavaScript to achieve this?

I am trying to prevent the accordion category from collapsing but when I click on the internal link (anchor element), it opens the new page but the bootstrap accordion chapter is collapsed. I needed help on that.

```js
$('#accordion').find('a').click(function (){

      localStorage.setItem("#accordion", $(this).closest('.collapse').index());
      localStorage.removeItem("#accordion");
      // Expand or collapse this panel.
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().toggleClass('active');

      // Hide the other panel.
      $("a").not($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()).removeClass('active');
  });
  
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var activeAccordion = localStorage.getItem("accordion");
        if(activeAccordion){
          $('#accordion #collapse('+activeAccordion+')').toggleClass('active');
        }
   });
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
<div class="card mb-2">
    <div class="card-header p-0 border-0" id="headingEight" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse8">
    <h5 class="mb-0">
       <button class="btn btn-link collapsed">
            <i class="fas fa-database fa-lg" style="color: #006666;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</i>Data | Kilobits
       </button>
     </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse8" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingEight" data-parent="#accordion">
       <div class="card-body pt-3 pb-0">
          <ul class="listNumbers">
              <li>
                 <a id="376" href="/Data/abc.php">Article 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                 <a id="377" href="/Data/xyz.php">Article 2</a>
              </li>   
          </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example), `aria-expanded` needs to be `true` for the accordion that needs to be opened up by default.

Comment: <li><a id="376" href="/Data/abc.php">Article 1</a></li>, I am talking about this link. When I click on this link , it should only open the new page without closing the accordion chapter. This link will be visible when the "area-expanded" will be true (this is clear to me).

Comment: You might need to handle the behaviour programmatically then. Refer to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#methods. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have added the javascript code and its not working. Can anyone please help me. I need to keep the accordion open upon clicking the anchor element click.